# angular2 - Cannot find module 'ng2-smart-table'

Tags: angular

I am trying to see of this datagrid module works.  Seem very very broken libary.

Here is how I installed for angular 2.4.x

```
npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:akveo/ng2-smart-table.git#v0.6.0-0 --save

ERROR in [default] /Users/Documents/frontend/qta-angular2/src/app/app.module.ts:28:36 
Cannot find module 'ng2-smart-table'.
```

Per the docs...I add the below into app.modules.ts

```
import { Ng2SmartTableModule } from 'ng2-smart-table';
```

I look at node_modules and it exists...

Why the error?

Answer (score 0):

> The library is available as npm package, so all you need to do is to
>   run the following command:

**`npm install --save ng2-smart-table`**

> First thing you need to do is to import the ng2-smart-table directives
>   into your component.

**`import { Ng2SmartTableModule } from 'ng2-smart-table';`**